# Wordpress. How to get post thumbnail without default class?

Tags: wordpress, class, post, thumbnails

I have a code for a thumbnail

```
$img = get_the_post_thumbnail (
    get_the_ID(), array(100, 100),
    array (
        'alt' => get_the_title(),
        'title' => get_the_title()
    )
);
```

Result:

```
<img width="100" height="100" src="http://formation.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/featured-image-vertical-150x150.jpg" rel="magnific" class="attachment-100x100 wp-post-image" alt="Template: Featured Image (Vertical)" title="Template: Featured Image (Vertical)">
```

How to get the same image without "wp-post-image" class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );


<img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" longdesc="URL_2" alt="Text_2" />
```

you can use function get_post_thumbnail_id() to get same image